# Adjectives made of nouns

Tags: adjectives

Can you show me the logic which is behind this:

> 1 He is a **six-year-old** boy. - correct
>
> 2 I hate the **eight-hour*s*-a-day** office routine. - correct
>
> But why not "**eight-hour-a-day**"?

What about these?

a two-centurie**s**-old tradition OR a two-century-old tradition

a 100-metre**s** race OR a 100-metre race

Comment: The measure expression is normally singular, e.g. " a three-inch nail", not *"a three-inches nail".

Comment: I think you’re looking for logic where there is none.  These are based on common usage rather than any particular rules.  Personally I’d be slightly more comfortable with eight-hour-a-day but can’t give any reason why it’s ok to use a singular where logic would call for a plural.

Comment: One possible reason is that a plural NP would be clumsy, c.f. "Two three-inches nails". The proximity of the plural noun base "inches" in the compound to the plural head noun "nails" sounds awful.

Comment: BillJ Did you read my question? Why is this not clumsy "eight-hours-a-day"?

Comment: OP, how does it make sense to refer to "eight-hour-a-day" when eight would make hour plural?

Comment: It's a funny question, you ask. How does it make sense not to pluralize "year" in "eight-year-old"?